# c# - Cannot convert from void to list

Tags: c#, forms, list, void

So, I got kind of stuck over my head while I tried to program something new.

I'm trying to add **objectBeer_pluche** or **objectBeer_Elektro** to my **OBJberenlijst** on the **Beren** Main form from the **details** Form, so I can add both instances of 2 classes to the same list.

I'm not even sure this is possible by the way. So, I would like feedback if what I am trying to do is possible to start with. I already figured VOID is not right but I am really clueless here.

This is my main **beren.cs** form with an **OBJberenlist**, that's where I try to add  **objectBeer_pluche** or **objectBeer_Elektro** into it:

```
public partial class Beren : Form
    {
    public interface Berenlijst { }
    public List<Berenlijst> OBJberenLijst = new List<Berenlijst>();
    public Beren()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Beren_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void BTNToevoegen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Details Details = new Details();

        if (Details.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            OBJberenLijst.Add(Details.getdetails());
        }
        Details.Close();
        Details.Dispose();
    }

   public void LijstLaden()
    {
        foreach(Beer berenobject in OBJberenLijst)
        {
            LST_beren.Items.Add(berenobject.Naam);
        }
    }
}
```

}

from this form called **details.cs**

```
public partial class Details : Form
{
    public Details()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BTN_toevoegen.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        BTN_cancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
    }

    private void Details_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RDB_pluche.Checked = true;
        BTN_ok.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void RDB_pluche_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PANEL_pluche.Visible = true;
        PANEL_elektro.Visible = false;
    }

    private void RDB_elektro_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PANEL_pluche.Visible = false;
        PANEL_elektro.Visible = true;
    }

    private void BTN_toevoegen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        open_foto.Filter = "jpg (*.jpg)|*.jpg|bmp(*.bmp)|*.bmp|png(*.png)|*.png";
        if (open_foto.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK && open_foto.FileName.Length > 0)
        {
            TXT_adres.Text = open_foto.FileName;
            PIC_beer.Image = Image.FromFile(open_foto.FileName);
        }

    }

    private void BTN_ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
    public void getdetails()
    {
        if (RDB_pluche.Enabled == true)
        {
            Pluche_Beer objectBeer_pluche = new Pluche_Beer(TXTNaam_pluche.Text, open_foto.FileName, "(Wasprogramma: " + TXT_wasprogramma.ToString() + " Graden Celsius");

        }
        else
        {
            Elektronische_Beer objectBeer_Elektro = new Elektronische_Beer(TXTNaam_elekro.Text, open_foto.FileName, "aantal Batterijen: " + CMBOBatterijen.ToString());

        }

    }


    private void Details_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox textBox = c as TextBox;
                if (textBox.Text != string.Empty)
                {
                    BTN_ok.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: seriously disordered question!

Comment: Details.getDetails is declared to return nothing (void) so the compiler is not happy when you try to add to your list the result of getDetails. You should return the object created there, but also this could fail if the two objects doens't have the same base class Berenlijst

Comment: i figured, I dont know how i could try to convert my question into a more logical one to understand, the core question is, how can i add an object created from a class on a form into a list on another form, should this help more?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is between this line...

> OBJberenLijst.Add(Details.getdetails());

...and this line.

> public void getdetails()

List.Add() requires an object to add, but getdetails() returns void. You probably want to change getdetails() to something like the following:

```
public Berenlijst getdetails()
{
    if (RDB_pluche.Enabled == true)
    {
        return new Pluche_Beer(TXTNaam_pluche.Text, open_foto.FileName, "(Wasprogramma: " + TXT_wasprogramma.ToString() + " Graden Celsius");

    }
        return new Elektronische_Beer(TXTNaam_elekro.Text, open_foto.FileName, "aantal Batterijen: " + CMBOBatterijen.ToString());

}
```

Hopefully Pluche_Beer and Elektronisch_Beer inherent from Berenlijst. Otherwise you'll have to revise your logic in a broader way.

Comment: thank you very much!
i had to change it to `public Beren.Berenlijst getdetails()` and it did exactly how i imagined it, i dont know yet why exactly it had to be like this , but im gonna study it for sure :)